# Insufficient privileges error on snowpipe with account admin role

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created a snowpipe to access s3 data in snowflake. I used the below query to pause the pipe which ran successfully.

```
use role accountadmin;
alter pipe PIPE1 set pipe_execution_paused = true;
```

But when I am trying to set pipe execution failed with the same above role it shows insuffiecient prileges error. I am trying following query.

```
use role accountadmin;
alter pipe PIPE1 set pipe_execution_paused = false;
```

Any idea whats going wrong here?? Thanks

Comment: Has the ownership of the pipe changed? Try using  SYSTEM$PIPE_FORCE_RESUME: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_pipe_force_resume.html#system-pipe-force-resume

Comment: @NickW Thanks that worked. Please post this as an answer so I can mark it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No probs, glad I could help.

Has the ownership of the pipe changed? Try using SYSTEM$PIPE_FORCE_RESUME: [Force Snowpipe](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_pipe_force_resume.html#system-pipe-force-resume)